# Adjust timeout of Weave overlay network when getting disconnected

Tags: networking, routing, docker, weave

I just ran an experiment to find out how long it takes Weave to recover from a broken connection. In my test setup node `A` is connected to node `B` through two paths. Path `1` has one hop and path `2` has two hops. So, initially, Weave routes the traffic through path `1` since it is shorter.

When breaking path `1` by bringing down the interface of one of the hops it takes around 60 seconds for Weave to react and reroute the traffic through path `2`.

I am checking the routing by having a look at the `weave report` output. More precisely, I am checking the information at `Router.Peers.UnicastRoutes`:

```
    "UnicastRoutes": [
        {
            "Dest": "2a:e4:6e:f0:57:ef",
            "Via": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6"
        },
        {
            "Dest": "66:c6:2f:12:02:05",
            "Via": "00:00:00:00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "Dest": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6",
            "Via": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6"
        },
        {
            "Dest": "a2:eb:a7:ed:41:b8",
            "Via": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6"
        },
        {
            "Dest": "06:8c:d2:06:2b:eb",
            "Via": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6"
        },
        {
            "Dest": "aa:be:7b:8b:a2:75",
            "Via": "76:5d:78:64:6d:a6"
        }
    ]
```

In this case the connection is already broken and all traffic is routed via the longer path `2`.

As mentioned, it takes around 60 seconds for Weave to notice that path `1` is broken. I am assuming, that there is a timeout to make sure that the connections is really down and won't recover. When I fix path `1` by bringing the interface back up, Weave updates its topology within less than one second, which indicates that it *can* react a lot faster.

So I was wondering **if there is a way to specify the time that Weave keeps trying to connect** before accepting that this connections is broken.

Comment: There is indeed a timeout responsible for the 60 seconds before it switches to the second route:
https://github.com/weaveworks/mesh/blob/5015f896ab62d3e9fe757456c757521ce0c3faff/router.go#L23
and there is currently no way to change this timeout.

Would you mind opening a new issue to describe the behaviour you would expect in https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues?

Comment: FYI, someone with a different username recently opened this GH issue: https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/2864
Feel free to vote and/or comment if it is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: @MarcCarré, I opened that issue ;) I am just using different usernames for those websites.